# Is it possible to set a different access permission to an specific file version using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Ok... let's say I defined versions `:high`, `:preview` and `:thumb` on my resource uploader.

I have `"config.fog_public = false"` set on my carrierwave config file and I'd like to be able to keep the access restricted to the original file and the `:high` version while allowing the `:thumb` and `:preview` versions to be public (not requiring an s3 signed url).

Does anyone know if this is posible?

If it is indeed possible what should I put inside my `:preview` and `:thumb` definitions regarding the access permission?

```
version :high, :if => :process_version_immediately? do
  process :resize_to_limit => [2048,1536]
end

version :preview, from_version: :high, :if => :process_version_immediately? do
  process :resize_to_limit => [640,480]
end

version :thumb, from_version: :preview, :if => :process_version_immediately? do
  process :manualcrop, :if => :croppable?
  process :manualrotation, :if => :rotable?
  process :resize_to_fit => [200,200]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I realized there's no way to do this using merely carrierwave, but by peeking inside the carrierwave objects I think I found a workaround to solve it using the fog gem, which is a dependency for the carrierwave gem.

I did a few tests through the rails console to prove my concept, basically what I did was to instantiate a fog object using my AWS fog credentials (the ones defined on my carrierwave config file).

This is the step-by-step of what I did:

```
fog_storage = Fog::Storage.new(:provider => 'AWS',
:aws_access_key_id => 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
:aws_secret_access_key  => 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', 
:region => 'THE_REGION_OF_YOUR_ACCOUNT')

fog_dir = storage.directories.get('THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_BUCKET')

# next, you need to find the object's path for the version you want to change 
# the permission access. Let's say the primary photo for a post in your private 
# blog or whatever
fog_file= fog_dir.files.get(post.photo.thumb.path)

# In my case I want that specific file version to be readable by everyone, so I set
# 'public-read' into AWS's Access Control List attribute or acl
fog_file.acl='public-read'

# and finish by saving the new property into the referenced object
fog_file.save
```

This did the trick for me... now it only depends on when to execute this logic. In my case, since my versions are processed in background, I'm going to implement it after the versions are created on my background process.

Wether this works or not, inside my app, I don't know yet since I still need to implement it. But in practice it worked over the rails console. I still need to check if this is going to create any kind of overhead on my servers, but it doesn't seem to be the case after the initials tests since the saving occurs on the AWS side.

I still want to check if I can get the fog object directly from my carrierwave managed resource field without having to instantiate a fog class.

I'll edit this answer with my progression for future reference by the community.